# same ref with 2 different id's MYSQL

Tags: mysql

My table contains a `Unique_ref` and postcodes and I need to run a report where I would like to see all records where 2 or more `post_codes` have the same `unique_ref`. Please could you help as I am not sure how to write this in `mysql`.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the above code is showing me now. what I wanted to see in the result was the 2 or more different post codes showing the same `unique_ref` so i can identify the properties based on the post codes.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT post_code, GROUP_CONCAT(unique_ref)
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY post_code
HAVING COUNT(unique_ref)>1
```